# Returning only values without a numeric character in it SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to only return values from a column that do not have a numeric character within that value.
example:

```
   yyyy INC 5.875% DUE 3/15/2014
   xxxx INC 6% DUE 4/15/2012
   x INC 6.625% DUE 9/15/2016
   xx INC 8.2% DUE 10/17/2003
   xy CORP REGISTERED 
   xy INC
```

I only want to return the last two records since there are no numeric characters in it.

I was playing around with

```
not like '%[^0-9.]%'
```

I know that how to return values that do not start with a value with a (+). I am just confused on how to do it over an entire value.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you would use `regexp_like()`.  To say that no digits are in the string:

```
where not regexp_like(col, '[0-9]')
```

Or, if you prefer something more positive, you can say that all the characters are not digits:

```
where regexp_like(col, '^[^0-9]*$')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRANSLATE` to strip the numeric characters and then test whether the value has changed:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value ) AS
SELECT 'yyyy INC 5.875% DUE 3/15/2014' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xxxx INC 6% DUE 4/15/2012'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'x INC 6.625% DUE 9/15/2016'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xx INC 8.2% DUE 10/17/2003'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy CORP REGISTERED'            FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy INC'                        FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  value = TRANSLATE( value, 'A1234567890', 'A' )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | VALUE              |
> | :----------------- |
> | xy CORP REGISTERED |
> | xy INC             |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6dd68f7642d3e129f8011443ed568f9a)*

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the patindex function, similar to the regex example:

where patindex('%[0-9]%', value) = 0